# "not-null property references a null or transient value" on bidirectional OneToMany, would expect Hibernate to fill property automatically

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Given the following entities

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "dispute_folder")
class DisputeFolderEntity {
    @Id
    var id: Long = 0L

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "disputeFolder", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    lateinit var postings: MutableList<DisputePostingEntity>
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "dispute_posting")
class DisputePostingEntity {
    @Id
    var id: Long = 0L

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "folder", nullable = false)
    lateinit var disputeFolder: DisputeFolderEntity
}
```

I'd expect to be able to save the folder (which owns the postings, from a business point of view) like this, with Hibernate/JPA resolving the relationship correctly:

```kotlin
val posting = DisputePostingEntity().apply {
    id = 12341L
}
val folder = DisputeFolderEntity().apply {
    id = 1234L
    postings = mutableListOf(posting)
}
entityManager.persist(folder)
```

Instead, hibernate throws a PropertyValueException

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value:
  com.example.jpatest.persistence.DisputePostingEntity.disputeFolder
```

Persisting the entity works fine if I set the reference in the "owned" entity, but I feel like this shouldn't be the way to handle this?

```kotlin
val folder = DisputeFolderEntity().apply {
    id = 1234L
}
val posting = DisputePostingEntity().apply {
    id = 12341L
    disputeFolder = folder
}
folder.postings = mutableListOf(posting)
entityManager.persist(folder)
```

My actual use case is a spring batch job, where I read a large XML file with multiple dispute folders and their postings (and additional relationships "owned" by the folder) and want to write them into our database using a simple `JpaItemWriterBuilder<DisputeFolder>`. I'd appreciate if I were able define the relationships via one-way property setting (on the owning folder), instead of having to set the values on both sides of the relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How should Hibernate know from which of all the possible `mappedBy` associations that such a *-to-one could be related to it should try to infer the value from? See, the way you mapped this, it is actually the other way around. You don't have to add the posting into the collection of postings, because that is irrelevant the association `DisputeFolderEntity.postings`, as the association is *mapped by* the `disputeFolder` attribute within `DisputePostingEntity`.

You can map it the other way round if you want and use `insertable = false, updatable = false` on `DisputePostingEntity.disputeFolder`, but this starts to look like it ought to be an embeddable.